# Creating BoxBufferGeometry from Box3

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to create a box mesh on the three.js scene, where points of the box mesh will be the same as bounding box of some existing object on the scene.

I have tried to create box mesh from box3 in the way displayed bellow, but i dont get the right result:

```
var threeObject = existing object on the scene;
var boundingBox = new THREE.Box3();
boundingBox.setFromObject(threeObject);

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var vertices = new Float32Array( [
boundingBox.min.x, boundingBox.min.y, boundingBox.min.z,  
boundingBox.min.x, boundingBox.max.y, boundingBox.min.z, 
boundingBox.min.x, boundingBox.min.y, boundingBox.max.z, 
boundingBox.min.x, boundingBox.max.y, boundingBox.max.z, 
boundingBox.max.x, boundingBox.min.y, boundingBox.min.z,  
boundingBox.max.x, boundingBox.max.y, boundingBox.min.z, 
boundingBox.max.x, boundingBox.min.y, boundingBox.max.z, 
boundingBox.max.x, boundingBox.max.y, boundingBox.max.z,
] );
geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
viewer.scene.add(mesh);
```

How can I create mesh box from box3? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vertices` array in your code holds vertex data but they actually represent face/triangle definitions. Hence, rendering just this geometry data results in a few random triangles (not visualizing a box).

You can solve this problem by adding an index to your geometry which will represent the face definitions based on your vertices. To understand this topic, you have to know the difference between indexed and non-indexed geometries. I suggest you study the official documentation page of [THREE.BufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry). There are for each type of geometry official code examples.

`three.js R107`

Answer (score 5):

In Three.js there's no automatic way to turn Box3 into a regular BoxBufferGeometry but here's how it worked for me

```
const threeObject = existing object on the scene;
const box3 = new THREE.Box3();

// conform to the object size like it's a boundingBox
box3.setFromObject(threeObject);

// make a BoxGeometry of the same size as Box3
const dimensions = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors( box3.max, box3.min );
const boxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(dimensions.x, dimensions.y, dimensions.z);

// move new mesh center so it's aligned with the original object
const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().setPosition(dimensions.addVectors(box3.min, box3.max).multiplyScalar( 0.5 ));
boxGeo.applyMatrix4(matrix);

// make a mesh
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffcc55 } ));
```

Comment: This example was super helpful and works great. Thank you!
I have one suggestion to simplify further: Since you have the original object anyway, you could use `mesh.position.copy(threeObject.position)` to position the new mesh instead of applying the matrix.

Comment: @NathanBlair the goal of applying the matrix is to move the center of the box so it's the same as the center of the mesh so when it's afterwards i.e. rotated it aligns with the mesh. This may require temporarily setting threeObject transforms to 0 before running this code, needs testing

Comment: hello from 2023,
`BoxBufferGeometry` is considered deprecated in `Threejs` and you should use `BoxGeometry` instead.
Also, `applyMatrix` should be replaced by `applyMatrix4`